# How to create a file on server and save it on server

Tags: asp.net, itext

I m creating a pdf file on the server using iTextSharp.
It is working fine prompting me to save everything is fine.
I have 2 scenario
1) I want to save this file on a location on server
2) I want to save this file in database

My Last line after finishing the code is

```
document.Close();
```

So can anyone guide me how can I do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method will create a new file on the disk with a paragraph in it. You could easily modify it to your needs.

Before this will work you must ensue the directory you wish to save to has the correct permissions set. Whatever user account the Application Pool for the website is using will need write access to the folder. Set this in Windows Explorer, Right Click > Properties > Security Tab. This is well documented on the internet.

You can store the filename in the database in many different ways and then link to the file from your UI. I suggest starting with a simple [ADO.Net tutorial](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ado.net%20tutorial&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-gb%3aIE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=fAdeTszWK9O68gPWyqWbAw)

```
protected void CreateDoc(string filename)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!")); 
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: How do I save it a specific folder, right now I m getting this message.
   Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\xyz.pdf' is denied.
I want it to save in a folder /PDF which is in the directory

Comment: This is working my friend the only this left is how can I save it in my project directory. Like my folder is in D drive d/Abc

Comment: Invoke the above method using CreateDoc("D:\ABCFolder\Filename.pdf");

Comment: I added this line CreateDoc(Server.MapPath("../FolderName/"+"/xyz.pdf"));

Comment: That should cut it, could be just CreateDoc(Server.MapPath("../FolderName/xyz.pdf")); however, no need for the string concat.